# Convert COUNT SQL query into Entity Framework query

Tags: linq-to-entities

Kindly any help me that how to write the below SQL query into Entity framework with Lambda Expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(SubCategoryName)
    FROM DC_SubSystem_Asset
    WHERE SubCategoryID=1 AND DC_CountryId=114 AND DC_LocationID=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a DBContext set up with all the entities, it might look something like:

```
int count = _context.DC_SubSystem_Assets.Count( a =>
    a.SubCategoryID == 1
    && a.DC_CountryId == 114
    && a.DC_LocationID == 1
    && a.SubCategoryName != null);
```

We need a `a.SubCategoryName != null` condition, because in SQL `COUNT(column_name)` doesn't include `NULL` values in the count;

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for quick response